# Does the axis of normalisation make difference in prediction in SVM?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, normalization

Suppose i have couple of values as follow :

```
x1       x2         x3            y
1        40         0.9           1
0.9      80         0.5           1
0.6      50         0.6           0
0.4      30         0.7           0
```

making the values look like :

```
x1       x2         x3           y
1        0.5       0.9           1
0.9      1         0.5           1
0.6      0.7       0.6           0
0.4      0.8       0.7           0
```

the column y is the output. Will it make a difference if I normalise along column x2 (axis=0) rather than along rows(axis=1)

will the predictions vary?

Can anyone explain the maths behind it?

Comment: What do the second values denote? (below "making the values look like:") x1, x2, x3 etc denotes features. Features can be in different dimensions(units like metre, cm, seconds etc) and scale. So it doesnt make any sense if you normalise it along rows. They should be normalised column wise to make any sense.

Comment: @Jibin Yes Vivek Kumar is right saying that normalization across rows does not make any sense. Normalizations across columns (or features) is done so that all the features are in the same range. This is done so that the distance computation which is there in an SVM is proper and the weight estimation for features is properly done. Normalization across rows would give ambiguous results.

Answer (score 1):

The prediction will vary. Moreover, it is recommended to scale the data for better prediction.
SVM uses a distance function (such as Euclidean distance) between feature vectors. If a feature has different values range it can have a unwanted high effect.

Consider the following example: we have 3 instances: A=(0, 80, 0), B=(1, 40, 0.9) and C=(0.1, 50, 0). If we expect that all features will be treated equally then we would like the distance between A and C would be smaller then B and C. However the distance function would result smaller distance between B and C.

Taken from the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html):

> Support Vector Machine algorithms are not scale invariant, so it is
>   highly recommended to scale your data. For example, scale each
>   attribute on the input vector X to [0,1] or [-1,+1], or standardize it
>   to have mean 0 and variance 1. Note that the same scaling must be
>   applied to the test vector to obtain meaningful results. See section
>   Preprocessing data for more details on scaling and normalization.